# Grails: Finding objects with List properties containing an object with a given property value

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm working on a Grails application.  We have a domain object called User, and User has as one of its properties a list of Role objects.  Role has a few properties, one of which is 'name'.

I need to find all User objects that have in their Role list property a role with a particular name.

```
User: List<Role> roles

Role: String name
```

So, given a list of users, I need to find all users that have a Role in their roles list property that has the name "SUPERUSER".

The database on the back end is MongoDB, so we can't use SQL queries or anything like that (the app does not use Hibernate at all).  Dynamic finders are OK, as would be a CriteriaBuilder solution, as far as I can tell.

Any help would be appreciated.  I imagine I am overlooking something obvious, as this doesn't seem to me that it should be so hard.  It wouldn't if I were writing SQL, at least.

Comment: `user.roles.contains(Role.findByName("SUPERUSER"))`

Comment: @james That's not it.  I'm not looking to return a boolean as to whether or not a user contains that role, I want a list of users that contain that role using GORM.

Comment: @tim_yates I don't see an actual edit there.

Comment: Oh, the groovy tag was dropped.  That makes sense, I suppose.

Comment: Is Role a domain object?  How are they mapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Role is a separate domain object, you can't do that directly, since mongo doesn't support joins.  The way this is generally accomplished in mongo is to embed a collection of roles inside the user object.  So if you model User like this:

```
class User {
    List roles
    static embedded = ['roles']
}
```

Then you'll be able to use a criteria or where query like this:

```
def superusers = User.where { roles.name == 'SUPERUSER' }
```

Comment: Yes, Role is a domain object.  It seemed that enums didn't marshall and unmarshall properly, which is how we had originally planned on doing it.  We had discussed embedding the objects.  Will have to see if that works.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this worked after marking the roles property as embedded.  I then could use superusers.list() to get the list of users I wanted.  @schmolly159 also suggested a criteria, and that worked, too - as long as the roles were embedded as well.

Comment: @MichaelOryl can we do the same thing by using dynamic finder. What if "Role" domain class has list of Address. How can we get list of addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HQL in this case (not tested, may need some adjustment):

```
def users = User.executeQuery("s from User s inner join UserRole ur on s = ur.user where ur.role = :role", [role: Role.findByName("MYROLE")])
```

Comment: No, mongo does not support that.  There's no Hibernate in this system.  I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: My bad, didn't saw that's mongo :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about a criteria query:

```
List superUsers = User.withCriteria {
    roles {
        eq('name', 'SUPERUSER')
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails because joins are not kosher when using mongo.  I'll try it again after embedding the roles as @ataylor suggests.

Comment: Worked after embedding the roles object within user.